# What is wrong with the MYSQL code?

Tags: php, mysql

Why will this code not execute.  Here is the error I am getting when I run it through PHPMYAD

Error
SQL query:

```
CREATE TABLE  'c4lpetitions'. 'Legalize-Raw-Milk-in-Wisconsin-1362871708' (
    'prefix'VARCHAR( 10 ) NULL ,
    'first'VARCHAR( 255 ) NULL ,
    'middle'VARCHAR( 255 ) NULL ,
    'last'VARCHAR( 255 ) NULL ,
    'suffix'VARCHAR( 10 ) NULL ,
    'email'VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ,
    'address'VARCHAR( 255 ) NULL ,
    'city'VARCHAR( 255 ) NULL ,
    'state'VARCHAR( 2 ) NULL ,
    'zip' INT NULL ,
    'timestamp'TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    )
```

MySQL said: Documentation

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''c4lpetitions'.'Legalize-Raw-Milk-in-Wisconsin-1362871708' ( 'prefix' VARCHAR(10' at line 1

Comment: just learn NOT to use the reserved words http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html so you don't need the nasty backticks not portable between databases engines and it isn't ANSI SQL.. using reserved keywords in programming isn't even possible so this should be an SQL anti pattern..

Comment: Aside from the core issue, it seems that you are creating a new table for every petition. Unless there are particular performance issues you are dealing with, you'll find it much easier to have a single user table, and a many:many table between that and a petitions table.

Comment: @halfer you don't completly know his application requirements but still it is an good comment.. if he indeed need to poll stats abouts all c4lpetitions tables he is in trouble because an complex inner join or union all statement is needed (what can cause performance issues unions are known to create temporary tables) .. this should have been partition tables..

Comment: @RaymondNijland, you can `SET SQL_MODE=ANSI_QUOTES` to use the standard double-quotes for identifier delimiters in MySQL. Using delimiters is necessary if your identifiers contain international characters, and I'm sure you wouldn't tell someone in another country they can't do that. :)

Comment: @Bill Karwin MySQL has many SQL modes.. SIDE NOTE: the more usefull ones are ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY (to avoid random data) or STRICT_ALL_TABLES (why MySQL truncate the data on defualt that does not fit within his space).. sounds like insert 100 Terabyte within 1 Byte space and i don't give an f... if you lose data..  note MySQL 5.6 defaults on using STRICT_ALL_TABLES

Comment: @Bill Karwin i don't fully understand your delimiters story can be the result of drinking Westmalle triple...

Comment: Ok thank you all I got the code working and removed the reserve words and the need for ticks

@halfer what I am doing is I have a table that contains all of the petition names and the user that created them.  Then I am creating a table for each petition to hold the signatures on those petitions.

Would there be a better way to do this?

Comment: @Todd, yes. Three tables, `petition`, `user`, `signature`. As Raymond says, if you want to see your most/least popular petition (just as an example) you want to have them all in the same table. The `signature` table is the many:many that just contains (petition_id, user_id) -- you insert a row into this table to sign a petition.

Comment: @halfer One thing though is that you do not have to be a user to sign a petition only to create a petition.  Thus I am basing unique signatures off of email address.  email address would be user_id then?

The way I am tracking the most popular petition right now is updating a row in the petitioninfo table (Which contains info for every petition) by one each time a new signatures is entered for that table.

Comment: Do the same as above, but have two user tables: `user_signatory` and `user_owner`. You can put just an email in the first one (with a unique index on it) and the much larger set of owner columns in the second. The table `signature` then will have a duple of (petition_id, user_signatory_id).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MySQL's escape-character is a backtick `, not a single-quote '.

I also suggest storing zip-codes as `char` strings rather than `ints` because a full-format zip-code, such as `12345-1234` is not an integer.

Comment: +1 for advice on postal codes. Also, [many countries have letters in their postal codes](http://www.theonion.com/articles/perky-canada-has-own-government-laws,19927/).

Comment: Additionally some postal codes may have a leading zero. But ` is also right. 
You can see that in PHPMYADMIN when doing queries over the GUI.

Comment: +1 for the char datatype... the backtick advise is bad.. see comment @ top

Comment: It was this and a combination of reserve words.  I did not know that using a - between words made MYSQL see the reserve words even withing a string of words such as Legalize-Raw-Milk-in-Wisconsin-1362871708 it was catching the work 'in'.  Removing the dashes made it work.

Answer (score 1):

Use back-ticks to delimit database/table/column identifiers, not single-quotes.

Single-quotes are for string literals or date literals.

Comment: Maybe an new chapter for your book? using reserved keywords in programming isn't even possible so this should be an SQL anti pattern because timestamp is an reserved keyword within MySQL.. if you use it just give me the credits :-)..

Comment: Yeah it's really uncommon but it's probably possible in some languages like Parrot or LISP or something.

Comment: @RaymondNijland, FWIW, `TIMESTAMP` is *not* a [reserved word in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html). It's kind of grandfathered in - i.e. treated specially because people use it so often as a column name.

Comment: if an hotel room is reserved you don't get it at all.. in mine point of view if an keyword is reserved.. that keyword should not be used not even when you hack it with backticks.. and you are right about TIMESTAMP but still this is an MySQL data type so you should apply "namespacing"..